# How to take the number of days in a year?

Tags: powerbi, dax

```
VAR period_end =
    FIRSTDATE ( general_dates_dim[День (дата)] ) - 365

VAR datediff_days =
    DATEDIFF (
        MIN ( general_dates_dim[День (дата)] ),
        MAX ( general_dates_dim[День (дата)] ),
        DAY
    )
VAR period_start = period_end - datediff_days
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SELECTEDMEASURE(),
        DATESBETWEEN ( general_dates_dim[День (дата)], period_start, period_end )
    )
```

I want to make the formula more universal and replace 365 with a function. To be able to watch the same day but a year earlier

[image]

Tried using:

```
VAR period_end = 
    FIRSTDATE ( general_dates_dim[День (дата)] ) - DAY(YEAR(TODAY()))
```

Comment: don't post formula / codes as screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific ask:

```
var daysInYear = VALUE( DATE(YEAR(TODAY()) + 1, 1, 1) - DATE(YEAR(TODAY()) + 1, 1, 1))
```

You can probably simplify your calculation to just:

```
CALCULATE (
  SELECTEDMEASURE(),
  SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR( general_dates_dim[День (дата)] )
)
```